# Python For loop not incrementing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
clean_offset = len(malware)

tuple_clean = []
tuple_malware = []

for i in malware:
    tuple_malware.append([malware.index(i), 0])
    print(malware.index(i))
    print(tuple_malware)
for j in clean:
    tuple_clean.append([(clean_offset + clean.index(j)), 1])
    print(clean.index(j))
    print(tuple_clean)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

training_data_size_mal = 0.8 * len(malware)
training_data_size_clean = 0.8 * len(clean)
```

i increments as normal and produces correct output however j remains at 0 for three loops and then jumps to 3. I don't understand this.

Comment: What do `clean` and `malware` look like?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the variables `malware` and `clean` are, but I suspect you're probably modifying a collection while looping over it which can have strange results.  (As an aside why do you have a variable called `tuple_clean` that's clearly a list, not a tuple?)

Comment: The loop with `j` won't run until the loop with `i` finishes. If you want nested loops then you have to nest them.

Comment: @Iguananaut I make tuple_clean into a list of tuples

Comment: Sorry @benvc, they're lists of hex values. Turns out that some of the values were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error on `clean.index(j)`.
Array.index will return the first matched index in that array.
So if there are some equal variables there will be some error

You can inspect with below code.

```
malware = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,2]
clean = [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4]

clean_offset = len(malware)

tuple_clean = []
tuple_malware = []

for i in malware:
    tuple_malware.append([malware.index(i), 0])
    print(malware.index(i))
    print(tuple_malware)
for j in clean:
    tuple_clean.append([(clean_offset + clean.index(j)), 1])
    print(clean.index(j))
    print(tuple_clean)

training_data_size_mal = 0.8 * len(malware)
training_data_size_clean = 0.8 * len(clean)
```

Comment: Thanks, logically I didn't need to check for this index so I just pulled out the .index() functions and left i and j. Although thanks helping me understand why j was playing up.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in something
```

a is what is contained in something, not the index

for example:

```
for n in [1, 10, 9, 3]:
    print(n)
```

gives

```
1
10
9
3
```

Comment: Isn't using .index() returning the position of the element? So I'm iterating through the elements and grabbing it's index.

Comment: j moves to the next element, therefore clean.index(j) should increment.

Comment: OK I see, I think you should clarify your question, try to make a self contained example (where all data is visible)

Answer (score 1):

You either want

```
for i in range(len(malware))
```

or

```
for i, element in enumerate(malware)
```

at which point the i is the count and the element in the malware.index(i)

The last one is considered best practice when needing both the index and the element at that index in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this along with an adaption based on Barkin's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

op has already figured the question, but in case anyone is wondering or needs a TL;DR of Barkin's comment, its just a small correction,

replace

```
for i in malware
```

```
for j in clean
```

with

```
for i in range(len(malware))
```

```
for j in range(len(clean))
```

and at the end remove the .index() function, and place i and j.